# "Push-to-deploy" GCP Feature

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I'm trying to use the Google Cloud Platform "[Push-to-deploy](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy)" feature in my Google AppEngine project, for my continuous delivery.

It's the first time I attempt to use it, and I am unable to create my VM.

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch image resource:
>    - The resource 'projects/bitnami-launchpad/global/images/bitnami-jenkins-1-587-0-linux-debian-7-x86-64-image' was not found

Did I miss something in my configuration ? Maybe it's just this version of the jenkins image that is unavailable ? How can I list the images available with the project bitnami-launchpad ?

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 3):

I have got my answer.
To obtain the list of bitnami images available, we have to set the gcloud current project to bitnami-launchpad, then we can list the images.

`gcloud config set project bitnami-launchpad
 gcloud compute images list`

And in the list, my Jenkins with the good version !

> bitnami-jenkins-1-598-0-r01-linux-debian-7-x86-64

Then :

`gcloud compute \
    instances create bitnami-jenkins \
    --project ${PROJECT_ID} \
    --image-project bitnami-launchpad \
    --image bitnami-jenkins-1-598-0-r01-linux-debian-7-x86-64 \
    --zone us-central1-a \
    --machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --metadata "bitnami-base-password=${PASSWORD}" \
               "bitnami-default-user=user" \
               "bitnami-key=jenkins" \
               "bitnami-name=Jenkins" \
               "bitnami-version=1-598-0-r01" \
               "bitnami-url=//bitnami.com/stack/jenkins" \
               "bitnami-description=Jenkins." \
               "startup-script-url=https://dl.google.com/dl/jenkins/p2dsetup/setup-script.sh" \
    --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" \
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control" \
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/projecthosting" \
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin" \
    --tags "bitnami-launchpad"`

creates a Jenkins Instance.

Comment: Or in one command: `gcloud compute images list --project=bitnami-launchpad` — see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/list).